# PDF link not working on webpage

Tags: html, pdf, hyperlink

Ok so I have a intranet webpage that I am making using HTML and I want to put a link (absolute or relative) on my page that opens a PDF. 
  The code I use is

```
<a href="http://harold.local/documents/sandP.pdf" target="_blank">Privacy and Security</a>
```

Now what ends up happening is that I get this error:

> 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.

Is there anything wrong with my code or where I am placing the document?

Thank You

Comment: Check your webserver's config to ensure that documents is a directory path that is accessible.

Comment: Your path is invalid. Please ensure that the path is correct. Please enter your path in browser and check if it is accessible or not

Comment: Also, typo in `docuements`. And is `<Privacy and Security/>` being replaced by something because as it is, it won't render as visible.

Comment: check whether the spelling of `docuements` is correct...is it `documents`?

Comment: if your link not work directly in the browser is not an html problem, is typo problem of your url

Comment: oops I did misspell documents, but on my code it is spelled correctly and still have the 404 error.

Comment: check if you can access the pdf by opening the page directly in browser.

Comment: that means, the link is broken...you dont have such a pdf in the specified link..

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on a local machine check the permissions on the PDF file that they are world readable. I have this happen a lot in my OS X web directory, some files dragged in seem to have different permissions.

Comment: Yea I checked and made sure it is shared.

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of small... oddities... in your sample line, which may or may not be significant in themselves, but could cause problems if you're doing any post-processing of the line before it goes live.

1. `http://harold.local/documents/sandP.pdf` is a good destination, correct? If you drop that by itself in to the address line of your browser, you can confirm that the PDF document can be found and displayed?
2. If you're doing any further processing of that string, should you be escaping the slashes or backslashes by doubling each one?
3. There's a stray space between your `target=` argument and your `_blank` value, again a possible risk if something later on will attempt to parse the string.
4. There is what appears to be a stray Left Angle Bracket (or Less Than) symbol ("<") immediately in front of your `Privacy and Security` text, which could be misinterpreted as the start of a `<p` tag, probably not what you want.

I would start by verifying the destination, then adding the context around it a bit at a time until something breaks. Failing that, find a similar working example of the `<a` usage on your local machine, and use that as a starting point for the link to your sandP.pdf document.

Comment: I've tried putting that in the address bar but it still shows an error. All the rest of the errors are were edited but still no luck.